# Arrange NULL at the end in each column of the table

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains two columns col1, col2.
NULL need to be placed at the end of each column.

Data in my table now.

```
---  ---
col1 col2
---  ---
1    null
2    2
3    null
4    4
null 5

create table mytable (
col1 number(3), 
col2 number(3)
);
insert into mytable values(1, null);
insert into mytable values(2, 2);
insert into mytable values(3, null);
insert into mytable values(4, 4);
insert into mytable values(null, 5);
```

I need to update them in this format.

```
---  ---
col1 col2
---  ---
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    null
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind such an update?  Or do you just need the 4 update & 1 delete commands to get the desired table?

Comment: @ScottHunter I have a report table (instead of col1, col2 - names of employees and values it's information about them)  of this format, the number of rows is much more, but the values are inserted together with NULL, I need to update them in the format shown above

Comment: can you provide a sample of actual data you want us to work with. right now the arbitrary numbers are hard, it seems like you want us to basically move the nulls to the end and stack the data so nulls are at the bottom of the record set

not sure if that is what you want exactly with out more context.

Comment: Can you explain *why* certain `col2` values are changed to what you want them changed to, and *why* certain rows are to be removed?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: if values for all columns are supplied, `insert into mytable values(1, null)` is absolutely standard SQL

Comment: *"if values for all columns are supplied, insert into mytable values(1, null) is absolutely standard SQL"* i some how doubt that for some reason @a_horse_with_no_name if it is indeed standard like you said it is not adviced to use as it is error prone..

Comment: i going to swallow mine words about making that comment that is it not standard ANSI/ISO SQL.. @a_horse_with_no_name `<insert statement> ::=
  INSERT INTO <insertion target> <insert columns and source>  <insert columns and source> ::=
    <from subquery>
  | <from constructor>
  | <from default>  <from subquery> ::=
  [ <left paren> <insert column list> <right paren> ]
      [ <override clause> ]
      <query expression>` -> the columns `[ <left paren> <insert column list> <right paren> ]` are indeed optional as it is between optional BNF..

Comment: @ScottHunter I have a report table with employees and countries where were they on a business trip.

But I need to update this table to format, where countries will be visible immediately after the name, without empty values.

Answer (score 0):

This *mostly* solves the problem; you'll need to put the final `update` in a recursive trigger so it executes the proper number of times.

```
-- remove nulls from col2
delete from mytable where col2 is null;

-- erase col1
update mytable  
set col1 = null;

-- add "footer" row
insert into mytable (col1,col2) values ((select count(*)+1 from mytable), null);

-- update col1 for 1 remaining record
update mytable
set col1 = (select count(*) from mytable where col1 is not null)
where col2 = (select min(col2) from mytable where col1 is null);
```